# Perl: CGI redirect from multiple submit buttons

Tags: perl, cgi, redirect

I have a small CGI Script with 2 submit buttons. I want that the current Script redirects the User to another script, depending on which submit button is pressed.

The CGi-Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Modules
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q                           = CGI->new();
print $q->header();
print $q->submit(-name=>'button',-value => 'disable');
print $q->submit(-name=>'button',-value => 'enable');

if ($q->param('button') eq "disable"){
         print $q->redirect(-uri=>"http://1.1.1.1./cgi-bin/services/switch_XXX.cgi?disable");
} elsf ($q->param('button') eq "enable"){
        print $q->redirect(-uri=>"http://1.1.1.1./cgi-bin/services/switch_XXX.cgi?enable");
} else {
}
```

But none of the actions is actually performed. The Error-Log shows the following:

```
[Tue Mar 06 11:48:44 2018] [error] [client XXXX] Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi line 23.
[Tue Mar 06 11:48:44 2018] [error] [client XXXX] Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi line 26.
```

Could someone of you tell me what causes the error and why the redirect is not working?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You've got your output and form handling code mixed up together

Comment: plus the HTML you are outputting isn't complete too

Comment: @ChrisTurner I just want to assign different actions to multiple submit buttons..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See ["Generating a redirection header"](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Generating-a-redirection-header) in the CGI docs: "If you use redirection like this, you should **not** print out a header as well."

The messages you're seeing in the log are referring to the `$q->param('button') eq "disable"` checks: `$q->param('button')` is returning `undef` because the field has not been submitted yet, so you're comparing `"disable"` to the undefined value. These are warning messages only, that you can avoid by first checking if `$q->param('button')` has a true value before doing the `eq` comparison. (Note: In other cases, one might want to use [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) to check for `undef`, because there are some values in Perl that are defined but still false, see [Truth and Falsehood](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood)  - but in this case, both `"disable"` and `"enable"` are true values.)

Also, your submit buttons need to be in a `<form>`. And note you've got a typo with `elsf`. This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new();
if ( $q->param('button') && $q->param('button') eq "disable" ) {
    print $q->redirect(-uri=>"...");
} elsif ( $q->param('button') && $q->param('button') eq "enable" ) {
    print $q->redirect(-uri=>"...");
} else {
    print $q->header();
    print $q->start_html;
    print $q->start_form;
    print $q->submit(-name=>'button', -value=>'disable');
    print $q->submit(-name=>'button', -value=>'enable');
    print $q->end_form;
    print $q->end_html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it working. I think its a bit confusing needing to check both buttons `$q->param('button') && $q->param('button')` in the if-statement. But as long as its working.

Comment: You can shorten that code a bit with e.g. `my $btn = $q->param('button') || ''; if ( $btn eq "disable" ) { ... } elsif ( $btn eq "enable" ) { ...` (the same issue with false-but-defined values applies; see also the [defined-or `//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or))

Answer (score 2):

If you are just starting to write web applications in Perl, I would urge you to read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) and decide whether you really want to use such old technology when newer and better (and still Perl-based) alternatives are available.

However, if you decide to stick with CGI (and CGI.pm) then there are a couple of things that can make your life easier.

**It's a rare CGI program that needs two CGI objects**

For most CGI programs, using an object-oriented approach is overkill. You rarely need objects. CGI.pm has a, simpler, function-based approach that you can use instead. Simply, import the functions that you want to use as you load the module:

```
use CGI qw[param header redirect];
```

Then use them without creating an object first:

```
if (param) {
  print redirect(...);
} else {
  print header(...);
}
```

**The CGI-Generation functions are a terrible idea**

It's even [in the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used).

> **HTML Generation functions should no longer be used**
>
> All HTML generation
>   functions within CGI.pm are no longer being maintained. Any issues,
>   bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they relate to fundamentally
>   broken page rendering.
>
> The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of CGI.pm
>   are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You
>   should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns.
>   See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for an example of using CGI.pm with the
>   [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit) module.
>
> These functions, and perldoc for them, are considered deprecated, they
>   are no longer being maintained and no fixes or features for them will
>   be accepted. They will, however, continue to exist in CGI.pm without
>   any deprecation warnings ("soft" deprecation) so you can continue to
>   use them if you really want to. All documentation for these functions
>   has been moved to [CGI::HTML::Functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI/HTML/Functions.pod).

Putting your HTML into an external template is a much better idea. And it will be easier for your front-end developer to edit. Yes, I realise you probably don't have a front-end developer on your project right now - but don't you want to plan ahead?

Having said that, your program becomes something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw[param header redirect];

my $disable_url = '...';
my $enable_url  = '...';

if (param('button') {
  if (param('button') eq 'disable') {
    print redirect($disable_url);
  } elsif (param('button') eq 'enable') {
    print redirect($enable_url);
  }
  exit;
} 

print header;
print $some_output_that_is_generated_from_a_template.
```

Comment: thats awesome! Couldn't understand my colleagues when they said build a cgi programm. Its deprecated and inefficient. Thanks I will look up your cgi alternatives.!